# What is someone who is a "problem solver" called?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang

There is someone that always when there is a problem he says: "No problem it will be OK". We know that we can trust that he will manage and solve this problem.

How do we describe this person? Something like a *managabalator* person? (Someone who manage things)

The same word. When there is a problem. He can say: "Don't worry it will be {missing word}"

In Hebrew we can say:

- אחד שמתסדר
- יהיה בסדר
- הוא מסתדר בחיים

This is a Hebrew slang. So, I accept slang answers.

By the way, you can think about *wizard*. "He is a wizard." But wizard solve problem in a magically way. This person just address the issue by using creative ways.

Comment: The person is called a *problem solver*.

Comment: The go to guy is how to describe this person

Comment: In English  it's "What to call...?" not  'How to call...?" unless you're asking how to use something.

Comment: What is "managablator"? Can you be more specific on what kind of problem (s)he solves and and why a "problem solver" can't be used? Please consider including an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used,

Comment: From an different perspective, are you referring to a "street smart" person? The meaning of this term is "shrewd resourcefulness needed to survive in an urban environment"

Comment: In American English slang, "wizard" is absolutely used to describe a person who is highly capable at solving problems in a complex field. E.g., "computer wizard" or "math wizard." I have no idea what the actual etymology is, but it may help you to think about the fact that to someone who is not well versed in in the field, what the person actually does seems more like some kind of arcane incantation than a logical sequence of steps, even if another skilled person would consider it obvious. I mention this as somewhat of an aside since it's not clear to me that this usage fits your situation.

Comment: Omnipotent, though it's not your purpose.

Comment: Wizard has always meant one who is wise.  Magical Wizards, Computer Wizards, Love Wizards are just people who know more than you about different things.  Magic has always been thus.  "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic" Arthur C Clark.

Comment: @Rathony Clearly a *managablator* is someone who routinely blates mother nagas.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that nobody has mentioned **savant** as being equivalent to a wizard, but without the connotation of being magical.

Comment: As a native Hebrew speaker, I must say I didn't exactly understand how the slang sentences in Hebrew had anything to do with problem solving. Roughly translated, the first one means -- ignoring the typo -- "one who gets along" (doesn't necessarily excel in problem solving, nor gets things done), the second one means "it'll be alright" (usually trying to assure that to someone else), and the last one means "he gets along in life" (very similar to the first).

Comment: When I say In Hebrew: "אל תדאג הוא מסתדר", I mean that he will solve the problem somehow. And I can say "יש לך בעיה. תביא לי, ויהיה בסדר".  In the two sentences, I mean problem-solving. I think the @ab2 answer "can-do" is exactly what I mean. Thank you for everyone!

Comment: Your [**managabalator**](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=managabalator) is totally made up, and nobody would ever understand its meaning. If it isn't manipulator, which exists, then you're probably thinking of "manage" as in bearing the burden of responsibility, and having the ability to organise oneself efficiently. Organiser, and [***solver***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/solver) are better terms.

Comment: @Drew Will someone convert Drew's comment (+16) into an answer, please?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: OK; done.

Answer (score 11):

He is a ***can-do*** person

**can-do**, from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/can-do):

> Marked by a willingness to tackle a job and get it done: "the city's
>   indomitable optimism and can-do spirit" (Christian Science Monitor).
>
> confident and resourceful in the face of challenges: a can-do attitude

To work with the sentence the OP wrote:

> When there is a problem, the can-do person says "Don't worry, can do, no
>   problem".

Or, if using slang, she might say (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_problemo)):

> ....no problemo!

Finally, sometimes a can-do person has to say "no can do"; then you know you *really* have a problem!

Comment: Can-do is more about attitude than aptitude. You can't necessarily "trust that he will manage and solve this problem," only that "he says: 'No problem it will be OK'."

Comment: @Kevin You have a point; one needs to ask questions and  have a good BS detector -- always.

Answer (score 9):

I call these people my "fixers". As a manager, I give them hard stuff, and I know they can make something happen.

Since slang is ok, I'll mosey to the urban dictionary:

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fixer

Comment: Bear in mind that this can, in some context, have the connotation of "assassin" or "guy who makes witnesses suddenly recant their testimony". In general, it's pretty obvious where that's true, though, and I doubt anyone will be confused by the term.

Answer (score 6):

The person is a *problem solver*.

> a thinker who focuses on the problem as stated and tries to synthesize information and knowledge to achieve a solution

-- [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/problem%20solver)

Comment: +1 for the everyday, usable,  and used,   word. Plus your comment suggesting this word has,   as of this moment, 17 upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with **troubleshooter**

[Wikipedia: Troubleshooting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troubleshooting%20Wikipedia%20Troubleshooting)

Answer (score 2):

In many fictional crime stories, a **cleaner** is called to clean up someone else's problem / mess.   Technically he/she does not solve the problem, but makes the problem go away.  This person is expected and trusted in this task as a professional with this one specific role.

My favorite character examples are Victor in La Femme Nikita and The Wolf in Quentin Tarantino's Pulp Fiction.

> *The Wolf*: You're... Jimmie, right? This is your house? 
>   *Jimmie*: Sure is. 
>   *The Wolf*: I'm Winston Wolfe. I solve problems.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleaner_(crime)

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, I know (unless you accept "magician"), but I can't resist posting it:

> There are two kinds of geniuses, the “ordinary” and the “magicians.” An ordinary genius is a fellow that you and I would be just as good as, if we were only many times better. There is no mystery as to how his mind works. Once we understand what they have done, we feel certain that we, too, could have done it. It is different with the magicians. They are, to use mathematical jargon, in the orthogonal complement of where we are and the working of their minds is for all intents and purposes incomprehensible. Even after we understand what they have done, the process by which they have done it is completely dark. They seldom, if ever, have students because they cannot be emulated and it must be terribly frustrating for a brilliant young mind to cope with the mysterious ways in which the magician’s mind works. Richard Feynman is a magician of the highest caliber.

—Mark Kac, quoted by James Gleick in *Genius*

Comment: I can't resist saying that it sounds like the "magicians" are just bad at explaining themselves. ;D If so, that would, of course, put Feynman in the former category.

Comment: He was an excellent communicator, so Kac's remark was rather off-target.

Answer (score 1):

[Thinker](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thinker) :

> someone who considers important subjects or produces new ideas

and in [another definition](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/thinker)  :

> someone who exercises the mind (usually in an effort to reach a decision)

Moreover, I came up with an invented word, **elixir person**, which has some occurrences when Googling!

Comment: With the caveat that it is often said that *thinkers are not doers*, so a thinker may think of a solution but not actually effect it.

Comment: @Clare, Agreed! (+1)

Answer (score 1):

In the days of machine politics, the late 19th and early 20th centuries in the United States, a person like this would often be employed as a "[ward heeler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward_heeler)" who solved the problems that came up in daily life for immigrants in exchange for their support at the ballot box come election time.

Adjectives often used to describe this quality in a person include "[resourceful](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resourceful)" and "[streetwise](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/streetwise)" (both per Merriam Webster).

Answer (score 0):

For a single-word noun you could say …

> "He’s a/the
>   [**master**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/master)" ...

in *Merriam Webster’s 2b sense:

> one that conquers or masters.

Or maybe its superlative sense as an adjective (d) in combination with @Drew ‘s “problem solver”:

> "He’s a/our **master** problem solver.**

Making it work for the "Don't worry it will be {missing word}" part of the question would be trickier, but maybe using the past participle of “master,” the verb (it’s “1- to become master of/OVERCOME” sense), could work:

> "Don't worry it (the problem) will be mastered."