# Person that solves problems by determination and hard work

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a word to define a person who with will, stubbornness, hard work and determination faces problem and solves them?
“Problem-solver” probably doesn’t fit because it involves mostly mental work. Who I have in mind is someone who takes responsibility and with hard work gets out of problems.

Comment: Such a person would be called _resolute_. Countless other words could describe such a person.

Comment: @ifthenelse Are you looking for a noun or an adjective, formal or informal, neutral, positive or negative? A meaningful sentence with the "word/phrase" as a blank would help.

Comment: @Greybeard an adjective or noun, possibly formal. Something like “He was a ***, a good guy and a hard worker. He always took the burden of responsibility and got out of problems”.

Comment: He was a Trojan - , a good guy and a hard worker. He always took the burden of responsibility and got **us** out of problems”.*"He's worked like a Trojan to upgrade the property and build the addition, but there's still a lot of maintenance"* (A Black Tie Affair and Other Mystery Stories By Elizabeth Elwood.) OED: **b. A brave or plucky fellow; a person of great energy or endurance: usually in *like a Trojan***

Comment: @Greybeard “resolute” was ok, but “Trojan” looks definitely better! Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that there's a single word for this, in part because such people are generally considered worthy of a multi-word description.

Comment: You said that you want a formal word, but your example sentence implies informality.

Comment: @Heartspring so you downvoted, right?

Comment: I did not downvote it. To downvote something, you need to believe that "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful" -  But you were fairly clear about what you wanted, an answer would be useful, and you've at least ruled an option. I was only noting the inconsistency so that you could clarify what exactly you were looking for :)

Comment: Well, reading this 3 years later doesn't sound formal, but the context actually was: I was providing a performance review for a colleague who worked intensely on a project. I needed the right word to highlight the devotion and commitment she put on her work.

FYI: in the end I went for "indomitable".
"[...]*** worked with indomitable effort to meet the deadline and provide an outcome of excellent quality.". I don't know if it's enough formal for a performance review, but it certainly helped :)

Answer (score 2):

**The word "[tenacious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tenacious)" comes to mind.**

*"Is there a word to define a person who with **will**, **stubbornness**, hard work and **determination** faces problem and solves them?*

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked up **go-getter**?

> an aggressively enterprising person

[Merriam-Webster]

Comment: I didn’t have in mind careerists or social climbers

Answer (score 0):

You could call such a person **industrious.** [The Free Dictionary defines it as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/industrious)

> working energetically and devotedly; hard-working; diligent

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- "bulldog," defined this way by [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/bulldog):

> *Informal.* a stubbornly persistent person.

- "workhorse", defined this way by [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/workhorse):

> a person who works tirelessly at a task, assumes extra duties, etc.

Answer (score -1):

The person could be called a **troubleshooter**. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/troubleshooter) has

> **troubleshooter**
> <sub>COUNTABLE NOUN</sub>
>
> A troubleshooter is a person whose job is to solve major problems or difficulties that occur in a company or government.

Comment: There seems to be a lack of "will, stubbornness, hard work and determination" in the meaning of *troubleshooter.*

Comment: @Greybeard aren't those the qualities which are required to *be* one?

Comment: Not necessarily. I suspect the best troubleshooters do their job with consummate ease.

Comment: I agree with you, Greybeard. I hit upon _troubleshooter_ as soon as I saw the question but reading further made me drop it.

Comment: @WeatherVane while yours is a notable answer, I think it fits specifically to a workplace context. The person I have in mind is one that takes responsibility of un/expected issues (by personal attitude), with hard work and willfulness, gets out of them.

Comment: If 'troubleshooter' is an accurate enough answer, then [What is someone who is a problem-solver called?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/366030/what-is-someone-who-is-a-problem-solver-called/371605#371605) is a duplicate.

Comment: @Greybeard experts *do* make their work look easy.

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed I think the OP is looking for someone who always appears to be "cycling uphill".

Comment: @Greybeard yes perhaps OP wants a word for someone who can *only* solve problems by hitting them square-on.

Answer (score -1):

I will base my answer in its most simple form. Of course derived from my mild obsession with William and his simple keen logic...  The word is simply..

"Fixer" Def: he or she is the sort of person who solves problems and gets things done.

Comment: Hi JD.  This would benefit from a source or citation.  Please do take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help] for how to [edit] your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Industrious, diligent, resilient or sedulous. I believe they were seeking more of a, "professional" definition to use. The others are synonymous, but perhaps not enough, "oomph", needing a more, "mature", word, to emphasize the,"appreciation", for the colleague.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).